# Assessing accuracy of profession stated on daughter's baptismal record

Tags: england, baptism-records, 1870s

While researching my great-grandmother, Celia Anna Gadd (1865-1915), I found a baptismal record dated December 15, 1872, which shows that she and her sisters Ada (b.1863) and Alice (b.1867) were baptized in Haggerston, Middlesex. The record shows that her father, Alfred Gadd (b. 1841), was a “professional singer”.

All the other records I have found of Alfred Gadd indicate he was a carver. These include: the 1861 census, Ada’s marriage certificate of 1882, and a Poor Law Removal Order of 1870 which states that Alfred apprenticed as a carver. The Removal Order, issued to his wife, Harriet, and their three children,  says they were abandoned by Alfred and  transfers them from Shoreditch, London to Bath, Alfred’s birthplace.

The only other record I have found of Alfred is on Celia Anna’s marriage certificate of 1883 in which Alfred is listed as deceased.

Why would the baptismal record show his profession as professional singer?